# when installing application insights, it keeps complaining about DiagnosticSource package version

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights

I am trying to install Application Insights on an Asp.Net MVC application by following this guide:
[Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net)

I have tried both Automatic and Manual configurations, but each time I keep getting the same error when running my application.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I have uninstalled and tried to manually install the specific version of the DiagnosticSource file but it keeps installing 4.3.0 which is the next stable build. Also I have removed any bindings from Web.Config.

```
    === Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/projects/***/App.UI.Web/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = *****\App.UI.Web\bin
Calling assembly : Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\projects\***\App.UI.Web\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\***\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/74ad50ed/1b8b2e6c/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/74ad50ed/1b8b2e6c/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/projects/**/App.UI.Web/bin/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Build Number
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule.Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +144
   System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass285_0.<ExecuteStepImpl>b__0() +26
   System.Web.StepInvoker.Invoke(Action executionStep) +107
   System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Invoke>b__0() +23
   Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule.OnExecuteRequestStep(HttpContextBase context, Action step) +64
   System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass284_0.<OnExecuteRequestStep>b__0(Action nextStepAction) +56
   System.Web.StepInvoker.Invoke(Action executionStep) +91
   System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Invoke>b__0() +23
   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule.OnExecuteRequestStep(HttpContextBase context, Action step) in /_/WEB/Src/Web/Web/ApplicationInsightsHttpModule.cs:164
   System.Web.<>c__DisplayClass284_0.<OnExecuteRequestStep>b__0(Action nextStepAction) +56
   System.Web.StepInvoker.Invoke(Action executionStep) +91
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +9956298
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +73
```

Comment: Downvoting because of no follow up

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the binding redirect for `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource` to your Web.config? Something like:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.0.4.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: What version of Application Insights did you install? Could you please provide the content of your `Web.config`,  `ApplicationInsights.config` and `packages.config` files?

Comment: BTW, remember to remove your instrumentation key before pasting the `ApplicationInsishgts.config` file's content here.